# How does a character is printed from binary?

Tags: character-encoding, characters

I know an ASCII character takes 8 bits but how do you print a character on screen with those bits?

Comment: What operating system?  Where?  command line?  programming language?

Comment: ASCII actually only takes 7 bits.

Comment: I really meant how a character is represented on screen. How does 7 bits make up a 'character print'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte is used as a lookup in a font table, and the appropriate pixels are lit for that character at the appropriate position.

Comment: What could be the maximum number of pixels allowed for character?

Comment: not only "the byte" but also (in unicode environments) any other glyph. you take the 'code', search for the visual representative in a lookup table and then you render it. ignacios answers is the correct one.

Comment: @user32344: you can lookup a glyph in a vector font ... so you can render it with as much pixels as you like.

Comment: It is completely dependent on the mechanism used for displaying the pixels on-screen, but a 8×16 cell is usually more than enough for PC text mode.

Comment: @user32355 Most fonts these days are represented by [vector information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics). That way there is virtually no maximum size limit to the font.

Comment: In the old days you could use a cell of 5x7 pixels. Its not very nice, or very readable, and lower case looks horrible.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can use a character's Alt character code to print it by pressing Alt + [code] on the Numpad. In some cases, the Alt character code coincides with its Unicode character code.

Example: Alt + 250 = ú

You can find the whole list of Alt codes by running the Character Map applications (charmap.exe).

Comment: -1: The code isn't Unicode. It's the [Windows Alt Key code](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codealt.html)

Comment: You're right. However, many Alt Key codes coincide with the character's Unicode character code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yep.. the ascii codes do overlap unicode. it's also possible to type unicode(in hex) from the numpad, but entering unicode like that may be dependent on application +1 to cancel the downvote of -1!

Answer (score 0):

You mean rather than doing

```
echo a
```

You want to type

```
echo 00111101
```

or something?

I think you'd have to convert it from binary to octal first.  Then you can do:

```
echo -e "\0141"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ printbin () { printf "\\$((2#$1/64*100+2#$1%64*10+2#$1%8))\n"; }
$ printbin 1000001
A
$ printbin 1100001
a
```